# How to fix this Excel VBA Overflow Error?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, overflow, integer-overflow

***portion of code with error***
[image: portion of code with error]

***vba overflow error***
[image: vba overflow error]

Hello. Do you know how I can edit my code to run the same equation shown here without error?
It seems that I am attempting to run or am resulting in a value that is too large as I get an overflow error.
The equation does run good if replace the 22897 number with 10000, but I need to run it with 22897.
I have tried defining variable "tram_slip" As Long with no success.

Comment: Scale your computation so it doesn't exceed the maximum allowed value for the data type you are using. If you need more assistance, please edit you question **after** reading [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also, especially, 
[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert everything to long

`tram_slip = CLng(2) * CLng(22897)` will work

`tram_slip = CLng(2) * 22897` will work

`tram_slip = 2 * 22897`will not work even if `tram_slip` is declared as `long`.

The reason is that VBA "thinks" that the result of 2 multiplied with whatever number will also be an integer like 2 unless you explicitly convert  beforehand.